# Fourier transform of sinc function.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let us consider the sinc function:
\begin{equation}
 {\rm{sinc}}(x)=
   \begin{cases}
   \frac{ \sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}  \qquad &x \not= 0,\\
   1\qquad & x=0,
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
What is the fourier transform, so-defined:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-\imath k x}dx$$
of sinc function? I can't calculate this integral:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {\rm{sinc}}(x) e^{-\imath k x}dx$$
Any suggepstion please?

Comment: Sine the function is not in $L^1$, you can only do it in the distributional sense. The answer, if I remember correctly, is $\chi_{[-1,1]}$, the characteristic function.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Properties.. Also, I have a FT table here that gives $$f(x) = \bigg(\frac{2\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg) sinc(\alpha x) \implies \hat f(k) = rect \bigg(\frac{k}{2\alpha}\bigg)$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \text{sinc}(x)$. We can rewrite

$$ f(x) = \text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{e^{i \pi x}-e^{-i \pi x}}{i x} = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int \limits_{- \pi}^{\pi}e^{i \omega x} \,d \omega = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{[-\pi, \pi]}).$$

Comment: Then $\mathcal{F} \left(\text{sinc}(x)\right)=\mathcal{F}\left(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{[-\pi, \pi]})\right)=1_{[-\pi, \pi]}$?

Comment: Yes @Mark. That's it.